# Http Requests within each other (variable issue)

Tags: jquery, json, api

I have a http request being made that calls over a token, that token is then parsed and used in variable called `response`. I would like like to use that varible in the next http request within the if command. Unfortunately, the normal method of calling a variable is not working. Can someone point me to the right direction.

I have seen the response and everything is coming up perfectly. However, the utoken within the variable `reponse` is not reading an output.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'https://yotpoapi.apiary.io/oauth/token');
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (this.readyState == 4) {
    if (typeof cb !== "undefined") {
      cb(this);
    }
    else {
      var response = JSON.parse(this.responseText)

      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'https://yotpoapi.apiary.io/apps/BLAHBLAH/purchases');
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

xhr.send("{\n \"utoken\": \"response.access_token\"\n}");   

    }
  }
};
xhr.send("{\n   \"client_id\": \"CLIENT ID\",\n   \"client_secret\": \"CLIENT SECRET\",\n   \"grant_type\": \"client_credentials\"\n}");
```

Output:

```
"utoken": "response.access_token",
```

Expected output:

```
"utoken": "123123213123123123123123123",
```

Comment: I suggest you look in to `$.ajax()` and `JSON.stringify()`

Comment: The output seems to be hardcoded:
xhr.send("{\n \"utoken\": \"response.access_token\"\n}")

Comment: @LarsJuelJensen We input the xhr.send with dynamic variables. Now we call ensure that the first bit of it is calling the usertoken. However, how can i take that user token  (stored in `response`) to the next function?

Comment: You should probably do it in that way: `xhr.send("{\n \"utoken\": \"" + response.access_token + "\"\n}");`

Comment: @JSG You are welcome :) Please mark my answer as a correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change this line:

```
xhr.send("{\n \"utoken\": \"response.access_token\"\n}");
```

To this:

```
xhr.send("{\n \"utoken\": \"" + response.access_token + "\"\n}"); // Added additional quotes for response.access_token
```

The reason is that you were sending `response.access_token` variable as a string, but should be as a varriable in a quotes.